# I cannot connect my dockerize symfonfy 4.2 project with mySql database in another container

Tags: php, docker, symfony, containers

I am trying to move an existing Symfony 4.2 project to a docker container with the existing database engine but the project doesn't seem to connect with the database.

As I viewed the log on the php-apache container, I saw this error message displayed **Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" ** And on a browser I got this message: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

These are my steps to set up the project on docker if needed to diagnose my issue

- Downloaded a php apache docker image using php-apache-7.4
- Downloaded MySQL 8.0 image, 5.4/5.7 isn't supported on the Mac M1 processor
- Note my docker-compose.yml file my environment: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
- I installed the following PHP module into the php apache container: pdo, MySQL, pdo_mysql and zip
- Created a self-signed SSL certificate and installed it on the PHP apache container
- The following ports were exposed 3304: MySQL, 80: web and 443: SSL port
- created a network without a subnet in the docker-compose.yml file
- added a name server test domain name in the /etc/hosts file on the local machine - restarted apache

Below is my full docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  abc-network:

services:
  #mysql
  mysql-service:
    image: mysql
    networks:
      - abc-network
    container_name: abc_db_container
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always

  #php
  php-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./symfony/Dockerfile
    container_name: abc_php_container
    networks:
      - abc-network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./symfony/docker/ssl/mycert.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt
      - ./symfony/docker/ssl/mycert.key:/etc/ssl/private/mycert.key
      - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
    depends_on:
      - mysql-service
```

Below is my DockerFile configuration

```
    # PHP + Apache
FROM php:7.4-apache

#Enable apache module and ssl self sign installation
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl && a2enmod socache_shmcb
RUN sed -i '/SSLCertificateFile.*snakeoil\.pem/c\SSLCertificateFile \/etc\/ssl\/certs\/mycert.crt' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf && sed -i '/SSLCertificateKeyFile.*snakeoil\.key/cSSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mycert.key\' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
RUN a2ensite default-ssl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y


#updates apt get and install essential php libraries
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libzip-dev git wget --no-install-recommends \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

#Install mysql driver for php and zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mysqli pdo_mysql zip;

#Installs composer
RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/download/2.0.9/composer.phar \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer

RUN chmod 777 /var/lib

#Copies ABC's virtual host conf file to the docker container
COPY ./symfony/docker/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
COPY ./symfony/docker/ssl-conf.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
#Copies ABC CMS Symfony project
COPY ./symfony /var/www/symfony/

#Points the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Comment: You should show your complete docker-compose.yml here.

Comment: where are you setting your connection details in symfony like DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name" ?

Comment: Can you please also show us your .env files or at least your database connection details. You should be using `mysql-service` as the host name in your symfony application. Docker alias containers on the same network.

Comment: Setting anything in `/etc/hosts`  on the host machine should not affect how the docker containers communicate between each other